# sed add additional column

Tags: character-encoding, sed

I want to add an additional column of ones to a tab separated file.
The file looks like this:

```
#> cat /tmp/myfile
Aal     Fisch_und_Fleisch
Aalsuppe        Fisch_und_Fleisch
```

The way I wanted to do it is by sed, matching the whole line, printing it out together with the new column. However the additional column is written in the middle of the lines instead of the end:

```
#> cat /tmp/myfile | sed 's#^\(.*\)$#\1\t1#g'
Aal     1isch_und_Fleisch
Aalsuppe1       Fisch_und_Fleisch
```

When I do a sanity check with some manually created lines it works, though:

```
#> echo -e "aaaaaaaaaa\taaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbb\tbbbbbbbb" | sed 's#^\(.*\)$#\1\t1#g'
aaaaaaaaaa      aaaaaaaaaaaa 1
bbbbbbb bbbbbbbb        1
```

I guessed it might be an encoding/line break issue, here is what `file` is saying:

```
#> file /tmp/myfile
/tmp/myfile: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

If it is an encoding/line break issue, how do I go about it?

Comment: Since you have `$` after the captured group, `sed` must be detecting a linebreak in the middle of the line, which seems quite strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce your exact issue, but have seen similar things before. Essentially, CRLF line endings can cause strangeness in the visual display, because the CR part, the carriage return, can cause the cursor to move to the begin of the same line, rather than to the beginning of a new line. Easiest is probably just to switch to Unix-style endings.

To switch to Unix-style endings, use one of

```
dos2unix
tr -d '\r'
```

As a whole, something like

```
cat /tmp/myfile | dos2unix | sed 's#^\(.*\)$#\1\t1#g'
```

If you need to switch back, you could use `unix2dos`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/$/\t1/' file
```

Comment: This is simpler than the OP's version, but the problem is not an incorrect `sed` command. The OP's command works, too.